# What is kerneloops applet in the Startup Application Preferences?

Tags: 17.10, startup-applications

I found this startup application in Ubuntu 17.10 and I am wondering what it's for.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The kerneloops applet allows the kerneloops crash reporting utility to ask a desktop user for permission before submitting an oops report to the oops.kernel.org website.

[Source](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kerneloops-applet/)

Comment: https://reposcope.com/package/kerneloops-applet